# Using random in php mysql can't random id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a sample code

```
products(id, name)
1 | Apple
2 | Sony
3 | Nokia
4 | Samsung
5 | LG
6 | Motorola
7 | Ekricson
```

And mysql:

```
SELECT id, name FROM `products` AS prod 
ORDER BY RAND(prod.id) LIMIT 5
```

When i run code is result is:

```
4 | ...
7 | ...
1 | ...
5 | ...
6 | ...
```

But next ... is result is:

```
4 | ...
7 | ...
1 | ...
5 | ...
6 | ...
```

Id not change when run random, how to fix ix

Comment: try taking out the prod.id from RAND() the argument is the seed value which is used to generate a _repeatable_ sequence of numbers. (according to the documentation)

Answer (score 7):

You should use `ORDER BY RAND()` and not `ORDER BY RAND(prod.product_id)`

From [RAND manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

```
RAND(), RAND(N)

Returns a random floating-point value v in the range 0 <= v < 1.0.
If a constant integer argument N is specified, it is used as the seed value
which produces a repeatable sequence of column values.
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument inside the `RAND(x)` function is the seed, so you're seeding it with the same value every time.  Instead, leave it as `RAND()` and it will be different.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id, name FROM `products` AS prod 
ORDER BY `RAND()` LIMIT 5

Answer (score 0):

You probably want just `ORDER BY RAND()` rather than `ORDER BY RAND(prod.id)` -- if you give RAND() an integer argument, it's used as the seed value, so you will always get the same "random" value back.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Use this way:

```
SELECT id, name FROM `products` AS prod 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5;
```

See manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)